# question regarding memory leak detection on instruments

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, xcode-instruments

I am using the instrument provided with XCode 4.3 to detect memory leaks. I am getting a memory leak in the following code line. Not sure why !

```
 self.view.backgroundColor=[[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background-non-retina.png"]];
```

Can anyone kindly tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`backgroundColor=[[UIColor`**alloc**`] init...`

Look carefully where it says `alloc`.  Anything you `alloc`, `init`, or `new` you are required to release.  Try using an autoreleased color, such as this:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background-non-retina.png"]];
```